# winrt - System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to write and read to local storage for Win8.  Using a helper I am able to successfully write to my machine, but reading the .xml file gives me a: *System.UnauthorizedAccessException occurred in mscorlib.dll* error

I created a codepaste so you can see my code.

http://codepaste.net/k9mht5

The code is failing here:

```
public async static Task<object> LoadData(string path, System.Type type)
{
    var _Folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    try
    {
        var _File = await Folder.GetFileAsync(path);

        using (IInputStream inStream = await _File.OpenSequentialReadAsync())

        {
            // Deserialize the Session State
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(type);
            return x.Deserialize(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message.ToString());
        dialog.ShowAsync();            
        return null; 
    }
}
```

Specifically on this line:

```
 using (IInputStream inStream = await _File.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
```

If you have any ideas on what I am doing incorrectly it would help me out a lot.
I am doing this in Release Preview.  If there is any other system information I need to give, please let me know.

Comment: You forgot to actually *use* the _Folder variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here is what I've noticed. In file `vehicleViewModel.cs` you call `SaveList();` and `GetList();` one after another. Both of these methods are declared as `async void` which means **fire and forget**. My idea is that while SaveList is trying to save, GetList is trying to read **one file at the same time**. I tried your code and I got the same error too. Try to change SaveList and GetList methods to be `async Task` and then use `await`:

```
await SaveList();
await GetList();
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: A 1000 Thank Yous! I'm going to try this tonight. By all accounts this looks to be the answer I need. I normally wouldn't have the Save and the Get right after each other but for testing this helper code I needed to get data in first and then read it. I'll mark this as the answer after I try it tonight! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use the dispatcher it will solve your problem

> `await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
>                       {
>                           // Your UI update code goes here!
>                           _dialogService.ShowMessage(rdm.ErrorMessage);
>                       });`